# Concurrent/Non-blocking console keyboard input

Tags: java, input, textinput, stdio

I'm working on a MUD in java. I read player input every tick, but I'm using `Scanner` which uses blocking operations. I want to have non-blocking input.

I've looked at the `nio` package which has a `Selector` class, but I'm not sure how to use it with regard to `System.in`. I figure I'll definitely need it once I'm running a server, but for now everything is offline.

I've tried extending the main class from `Applet` and overriding `keyDown`, but that just meant input was no longer accepted after the first one. Sure, I wasn't blocking anything anymore, but then there was no more input. `keyDown` never got called again, I guess.

Perhaps threads can be interrupted even when they are executing blocking operations?

Thanks for any insight into this problem.

Comment: Non-blocking sockets (networking) aren't done the same way as non-blocking IO, at least not in most enviroments.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with the system console because by now it can't be done in a multi-platform way.

You can use swing window as console or find a JNI based approach but it might not work on some platforms.

You may use [JCurses](http://javacurses.sourceforge.net/). It might work, it's based on JNI and supports Windows and Linux.

Comment: JCurses is built on UNIX `curses` so it will definitely work.

Comment: As of 2014-05-23, the `explanation` link is dead (now links to domain parking page).

Comment: @daveloyall I removed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

keyDown() is [deprecated](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#keyDown%28java.awt.Event,%20int%29) so I'd suggest to use [processKeyEvent](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#processKeyEvent%28java.awt.event.KeyEvent%29) and a [keyListener](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html) instead.

> Perhaps threads can be interrupted even when they are executing blocking operations?

Yes if you have a reference to the thread object you want to interrupt, you can simply call [interrupt()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) method on that instance. And in the run method of the thread you can handle the interrupted exception. However, this seems a little bit hack-ish. I don't see how this is more helpful than using a simple KeyListener.

Comment: Thread.interrupt() only sets the interrupt flag and wakes up thread if it's sleeping or blocked. It does not interrupt regular blocking file IO of socket read. It will also not interrupt a heavy calculation or a spinlock - your code needs to check and obey the 'interrupted' flag in order to be interruptable.

Answer (score -1):

JLine might fit your bill as well:

http://jline.sourceforge.net/apidocs/src-html/jline/ConsoleReader.html#line.1447

Comment: downvote: The above links to `ConsoleReader.readVirtualKey` which is a blocking operation.

Answer (score -1):

I had had to solve similar problem with blocking writing/reading from http. In that particular case I used local buffer and Threads.

Idea is simple, one Thread read from stdin and put content in buffer. Second do same with writing.

And then you use nonblocking queries into your buffer.

Sample code:

```
class NonBlockingReader implements Runnable{
  Reader in;
  List buffer;
  public void run(){
    String line=null;
    while((line=in.readLine())!=null){
      storeLine(line);
    }
  }
  private synchronized storeLine(String line){
    buffer.add(line);
  }
  public synchronized String getLine(){
    if(list.size()>0)
       return list.removeFirst();
    return null;
  }
}

// .. same for writer, then you jast pass stdin and stdout ...
```

Comment: the System.in stream which is the Java's stdin equivalent is buffered, so the app does not see the characters until user presses enter.