# Java is there a way to see if a key was press without blocking?

Tags: java

I have a bot program to test my server.  I would like it to exit the loop if any key was press, but do not want it to stop and wait until a key was press.  thus the loop would keep running until any key on the keyboard was press.

This is how I'm trying to do it now, but does not work

```
        if (System.in.available()>0)
        {
            System.out.println("key pressed");
            break; // exit loop
        }
```

Comment: you need to press enter or ctrl-d java only offers full lines

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concurrent/Non-blocking console keyboard input in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249680/concurrent-non-blocking-console-keyboard-input-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options are:

- **Create a GUI window**. You can can receive asynchronous key events from an awt/swing window via key event listener.

  See code sample in last answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606989/read-any-key-to-continue-java).
- **Create separate thread** in your program to wait for enter key press and then signal the main loop thread to end.
- **Use a native library** like [jInput](http://www.newdawnsoftware.com/resources/jinput/) or [jLine](http://jline.sourceforge.net) (or write your own simpler equivalent using jni/jna).

  This allows you hook in to native OS's asynchronous key handling, although even then, there are often subtle dependencies on a windowing system being in place first.

Comment: Hi,This seems awful complicated, there is no way to simply see if a key is down or not???????

Comment: I agree it seems overly complicated, but that's the way it is in Java console apps.